# Returning custom fields in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, schema-design, nosql

I have a mongoDB collection with an array field that represents the lists the user is member of.

```
user { 
  screen_name: string
  listed_in: ['list1', 'list2', 'list3', ...] //Could be more than 10000 elements (I'm aware of the BSON 16MB limits)
}
```

I am using the *listed_in* field to get the members list

```
db.user.find({'listed_in': 'list2'});
```

I also need to query for a specific user and know if he is member of certain lists

```
var user1 = db.findOne({'screen_name': 'user1'});
```

In this case I will get the *listed_in* field with all its members.

My question is:
Is there a way to pre-compute custom fields in mongoDB?
I would need to be able to get fields like these, *user1.isInList1*, *user1.isInList2*

Right now I have to do it in the client side by iterating through the *listed_in* array to know if the user is member of "list1" but *listed_in* could have thousand elements.

Comment: When you say you want results like: `user1.isInList1`, does that mean you want mongo to set a boolean key at the root level of the document for every list that exists? Wouldn't that be pretty unpredictable to use? Could you maybe explain one step further about the problem you want to accomplish with the ultimate result object? Also, if you plan to make that document fast and index the listed_in, I believe there is a default 5k element limit for an indexed list. You can raise it though

Comment: Where I can find more info about the 5k element limit for an indexed list? I haven't hear about it before.

Comment: Strange. Im doing my first MongoDB project right now and when I was researching indexing arrays I came across information that said there was a 5k element limit to indexed arrays. Now, I cant find that anymore. I'm VERY happy to be wrong on this if I am :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My question is: Is there a way to pre-compute custom fields in mongoDB?

Not really. MongoDB does not have any notion of "computed columns". So the query you're looking for doesn't exist.

> Right now I have to do it in the client side by iterating through the *listed_in* array to know if the user is member of "list1" but *listed_in* could have thousand elements

In your case you're basically trying to push a client-side `for` loop onto the server. However, some process still has to do the `for` loop. And frankly, looping through 10k items is not really that much work for either client or server.

The only real savings here is preventing extra data on the network.

If you really want to save that network traffic, you will need to restructure your data model. This re-structure will likely involve two queries to read and write, but less data over the wire. But that's the trade-off.

Comment: Yes my concern is about network traffic too. Could you give me more details about your ideas to re-structure the model?

Comment: You basically just build a "join" table like you would in SQL. So you build a collection containing two fields: `screen_name` and `list`, then you index on both fields. Now you can do an indexed query for `screen_name/list` and only return the minimum set of data. The trade-off is that you need to maintain both copies of the data *or* you need to accept that one of the queries is going to be sub-optimal.

Comment: Each list could have up to 10M members. This is my first project using Mongo, do you think MongoDB will works correctly on a collection with more than 1 billion documents?

Comment: Also if I use the "join" table, I'll need to make this kind of queries on the user collection (~200M docs) ´db.user.find({_id : {'$in' : [id1, id2..., id10M]} })´, not sure how long will take this query. That's why I am trying to get everything inside the "user" collection.

Comment: MongoDB can handle billions of documents, but lists with millions of members is not likely to work. A single MongoDB document has a 16MB size limit. So a 10M item array inside of your document will break that limit. You will likely have to model this as three collections and write a bunch of "manual joins".