# Mongo Select Custom Fields

Tags: mongodb

Lets assume that i have a collection that contains

```
_id
first_name
last_name
...
```

how can I select all fields including custom like the following:

```
db.collection_name.findOne({},{*,$full_name:{$value:first_name+' '+last_name}});
```

*This is just an example.*

how can we select all fields with some custom fields like `full_name`

where

```
full_name=first_name+' '+last_name
```

Comment: Duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8639646/returning-custom-fields-in-mongodb

Comment: custom fields in mongodb?